# Using putty to patch to cloze module

Tags: 7, version-control

I use [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) to apply [cloze](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloze) module [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/cloze-report_form_quiz_compatibility_fixed-2216049-1.patch). Here are my steps:

1. I go to this directory: sites/all/modules/contrib/cloze
2. I save the patch: wget https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/cloze-report_form_quiz_compatibility_fixed-2216049-1.patch
   Save as: cloze-report_form_quiz_compatibility_fixed-2216049-1.patch
3. I apply patch: git apply cloze-report_form_quiz_compatibility_fixed-2216049-1.patch (nothing happen. no error)
4. I check the status: git status

Result:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

How come?

Comment: Because the folder you're executing `git` in is not a git repository

Comment: @Clive, I had added the question

Comment: `git apply` works only on tracked files, so if you're not source controlling your current file that you're trying to apply a patch to, then just do `patch -p1 < patchname.patch` instead of `git apply`

Comment: @Beebee, Thanks. I learn how to patch a file from you. However, this patch never help me to solve my problem. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your step 1, make sure to initialize the GIT repository, which will add the `.git` directory, subdirectories and files that store your repository data.

To do so, just use command `git init` while in your directory `sites/all/modules/contrib/cloze`.

If you're new to using GIT with Drupal, you may want to look at the community documentation located at [Building a Drupal site with Git](https://www.drupal.org/node/803746) (+ its child pages).

Comment: Vriens, I had edited the question

Comment: Please don't do that @learnallskill - once a question has been answered (and correctly as in this case), you can't edit it to ask a different question altogether. It invalidates the existing answer which is both unfair to the person who answered it, and confusing for people who come across the question again. With the best will in the world, I don't think you need help with Drupal, but instead need to get a basic understanding of how git works. We can't help with that here, unless there's something very specific about Drupal you need to know. The edit you made was a generic git question

Comment: (as is this one, so don't be too surprised if the community eventually vote to close this)

Comment: @learnallskill I'll leave it for the community to decide on something like this, it's always useful to know this sort of stuff in a Drupal context so it's a bit of a grey area. Just in case you do need a starting-place for git, [this free book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is excellent BTW